# How to print binary file as bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

I did

```
>>> b0 = open('file','rb')
```

Then

```
>>> b0.read(10)
```

gives

```
b'\xb8\xaaK\x1e^J)\xab_I'
```

How can I get things printed all as pure hex bytes? I want

```
b'\xb8\xaa\x4b\x1e\x5e\x4a\x29\xab\x5f\x49'
```

(PS: is it possible to print it pretty? like

```
B8 AA 4B 1E 5E 4A 29 AB 5F 49
```

or colon separated.)

Comment: `string.encode('hex')`? :)

Comment: @Allendar - no, in pyhon3 that doesn't work. `binascii.hexlify`

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> s = b'\xb8\xaaK\x1e^J)\xab_I'
>>> ' '.join('{:02X}'.format(c) for c in s)
'B8 AA 4B 1E 5E 4A 29 AB 5F 49'
```

or, slightly more concisely:

```
>>> ' '.join(map('{:02X}'.format, s))
'B8 AA 4B 1E 5E 4A 29 AB 5F 49'
```

Comment: I found this in another answer. It's kind of indirect. Is there a way to set some environment variable so that bytes are printed as is?

Comment: And `0`'s are printed as `0`, not `00`, e.g. I got something like `1 0 F2 5 2A 1 0 0 0 43 41 4 96`, which is not so good.